# Java Integer Accumulator optimisation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I need to write Integer Accumulator. Implementation needs to be thread-safe and efficient under high thread contention.

Usage example:

```
Accumulator accumulator = new AccumulatorSum();
int firstSum = accumulator.accumulate(1, 2, 3);
int secondSum = accumulator.accumulate(4);
int total = accumulator.getTotal();
```

In this case, the value of `firstSum` is 6, `secondSum` is 4 and the value of `total` is 10. 
Calling `accumulator.reset()` would reset the `total` value to 0.

Code below is something that I've managed to do. Do you think it is thread-safe, guarantees consistency and efficient enough?

Thanks for any help!

```
public class AccumulatorSum implements Accumulator{

    private ReadWriteLock rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private Integer totalSum = 0;

    @Override
    public int accumulate(int... values) {

        int sum = 0;
        for(int v : values){
            sum += v;
        }

        rwlock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            totalSum += sum;
        }
        finally {
            rwlock.writeLock().unlock();
        }

        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotal() {
        rwlock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            return totalSum;
        }
        finally {
            rwlock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        rwlock.writeLock().lock();
        try{
            totalSum = 0;
        }
        finally {
            rwlock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know...`AtomicInteger` takes care of practically all of your use cases...

Comment: Or even better: [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)

Comment: Why does the sum of the `values` argument need to be part of the `Accumulator`? You can do that yourself.

Comment: Why LongAccumulator has been introduced in java 8 then?

Comment: I don't see the relation between the two or what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, from java doc: LongAccumulater under high contention, expected throughput is significantly higher over AtomicInteger. Thats why I am asking if due jvm / CPU cache is possible to optimize my solution.

Comment: You aren't replying to any of the comments then? The source code of both `LongAdder` and `LongAccumulator` are available to you. Go check how Doug Lea does it and try to do it too.

Comment: Can you post your code with your threads; I'm trying to figure out what varablies are shared by the threads and then identify a potential race conditiion